# Best way to dynamically build complex HTML elements returned by Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `<div>` which should get populated with a form on Mouse click.

I have lined up the jQuery for this by sending the request to the server and the server returning me the form as simple text. However if I use `innerHTML` to add the contents to the will it be accessible to say, the Validation plugin of jQuery to validate the form that was sent by the server and inserted into the `<div>`.

I know of a method of manually creating each DOM element but the form is too complex to be created manually!

Which method would suit my situation the best?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [jQuery Form Validation Not Working on Newly-Created Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142609/jquery-form-validation-not-working-on-newly-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Using validation plugin as example, you simply call the plugin within the succcess callback of the ajax, once the new html exists.

Simplified version using jQuery `load()` ajax shortcut method

```
$('#contentDiv').load('formUrl.php',function(){
    /* form now exists, can add validation*/
    $('#myNewForm').validate( /* ootions object */);

})
```

Comment: Will the Validation Plugin be able to access the elements of the form if I just dump the form text returned by the server into the <div> using innerHTML?

Comment: assuming you are returning text/html yes...but it has to be in success callback of your ajax. The form must exist before you call the validation plugin